# Change Add to cart button text based on shopping cart price rule

Tags: addtocart

I am looking for a solution to Change Add to cart button text based on shopping cart price rule in product list page and product view page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, unless you have other products in your cart before.

> Shopping cart price rules create discounts for orders at the checkout
>   level, based on a set of conditions. The discount can be applied
>   automatically when the conditions are met, or be applied when the
>   customer enters a valid coupon code. When applied, the discount
>   appears on the shopping cart page under the subtotal. Once
>   established, the price rule can be used as needed for a season or
>   promotion by changing its status and date range.

Link: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide-Jan-29/content/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html